# java.lang.NumberFormatException: null with jsp and tomcat

Tags: html, jsp, tomcat, exception, numberformatexception

I´m trying to open my battle.jsp and this Error appears

[image]

this is the part my first jsp page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="firstPage.css">
```

```
<div class="container">
    
    <div class="header">
    <h1>RPG</h1>
    </div>
    

    <div class="left">
        <img src="images/hero.png" width="300" height="300" class="hero">
        <input type="number" class="heroNumber" min="1" max="3" value="1" name="heroes"> 
    </div>


    
    <div class="middle">
        <p class="VS">VS.</p>
            <form action="battle.jsp" method="post" name="form1">
                <input type="submit" value="Fight" class="submitFight">
            </form>
    </div>

    
    
    <div class="right2">
        <img src="images/wolf.png" width="152" height="150" class="wolf">
        <input type="number" class="wolfNumber" min="1" max="5" value="1" name="wolfs"> 
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="right2">
        <img src="images/orc.png" width="150" height="150" class="orc">
        <input type="number" class="orcNumber" min="1"max="3" value="1" name="orcs">
    </div>
```

and this is the part of the second (why the error appears):

```
<%
int amountOrc = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("orcs"));
int amountWolf = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("wolfs"));
int amountHero = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("heroes"));
```

everything worked before but now this error appears

Comment: Hi your form tag only have submit button inside it all other inputs are outside form tag so no value are getting submitted .Put all `inputs` inside `form` tag that should work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your data has to be submitted through a `<form>`. All data submitted outside of a form will not be received by the servlet.

Therefore your code should be:

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="/path" method="POST">
    <div class="header">
    <h1>RPG</h1>
    </div>
    

    <div class="left">
        <img src="images/hero.png" width="300" height="300" class="hero">
        <input type="number" class="heroNumber" min="1" max="3" value="1" name="heroes"> 
    </div>


    
    <div class="middle">
        <p class="VS">VS.</p>
            <form action="battle.jsp" method="post" name="form1">
                <input type="submit" value="Fight" class="submitFight">
            </form>
    </div>

    
    
    <div class="right2">
        <img src="images/wolf.png" width="152" height="150" class="wolf">
        <input type="number" class="wolfNumber" min="1" max="5" value="1" name="wolfs"> 
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="right2">
        <img src="images/orc.png" width="150" height="150" class="orc">
        <input type="number" class="orcNumber" min="1"max="3" value="1" name="orcs">
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Also, I would recommend not using this:

```
int amountOrc = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("orcs"));
int amountWolf = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("wolfs"));
int amountHero = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("heroes"));
```

But using this:

```
String orcs = request.getParameter("orcs");
String wolfs = request.getParameter("wolfs");
String heroes = request.getParameter("heroes");
if(orcs!=null&&wolfs!=null&&heroes!=null){
    int amountOrc = Integer.parseInt(orcs);
    int amountWolf = Integer.parseInt(wolfs);
    int amountHero = Integer.parseInt(heroes);
}
```

To avoid `NullPointerExceptions` or a user's attempt to throw one, anyway.